# Are Repositories shared among Spring Boot Services?

Tags: spring-boot, post, repository

My current Spring Boot application has the structure:

```
RestController > Service > Repository
```

That is to say, the Controller contains a service and that service contains a repository reference.

I am looking to add a new service to deal with receiving POST requests and need access to the repository. How do I get access to the repository from this new service? Will I end up doing everything from one service, or the main controller?

Are there any annotations I can use?

Comment: Aren't you auto-wiring the repository to your service and your service to the controller? If that's the case, you can auto-wire the same repository to another service.

Comment: Okay, I wasn't sure if auto-wiring made it act as a "singleton" or not, in the sense that there would only be one.

Comment: There would only one repository bean but it will be injected in both the services by dependency injection(DI).